# Python: Os Filesize returning Garbage for /dev/core

Tags: python, file, permissions, operating-system

I've written a python script that goes through my filesystem (LINUX) and collects the sizes of files.

Here is the relevant bit:

```
for name in files:
file_name = os.path.join(root,name)
file_size = os.stat(p).st_size
if x>1000000000000:
    print x, p
```

So the script returns the size and path of any files greater than a terabyte in size. (There are no such files on my system --- my SSD space is 120GB.) It prints the following output:

```
140737486266368 /dev/core
140737486266368 /proc/kcore
```

But I know that these files are not this large. Why am I getting these erroneous value?

I should note that I have run the script as root. I have permission to access these files. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that files in `/dev` and `/proc` are not ordinary files but just views into devices and, e.g., kernel. If you check the size of that file (it is actually the same file, just symlinked), you will notice that even `ls -l` reports an insanely large size.

The best approach is to skip at least `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, and `/run` folders (thanks, `user3553031`). Another possibility would be to check the file attributes - they'll reveal these are special files. However, it might be easier to just ignore the special folders.

Unfortunately, this is highly OS specific, and the above instructions are for Linux. Even different distributions may have different special files, and BSD, Windows &c. may act differently.

Comment: Also exclude /sys and /run.  And if you have any chroots that mount any of the above, exclude those as well.